# Read acces to central administration

Tags: central-administration

I would want to have read access to the central administration of our sharepoint environment. Now my administrator refused this, because he would have to give me too much rights. I do respect his reasons, but still just want to read access and nog write anything.

Preferrable a no code and not a third party solution.

Greetz,
Ron

Answer (score 1):

Central Administration is only for Administrators not for normal users. Your administrator can't give you just read access.

However I find this article on TechNet that explains adding users to Central Admin site and I guess it might be possible to give them read permission only as I never tried it myself.

[Designate visitors, members, and owners for the Central Administration site](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263210%28office.12%29.aspx#section5)

May I know why you want access to central administration as we might find a way out.